# Too Many Rows Were Affected error on updating a Transact SQL linked table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, linked-server

I am trying to update a linked table with this...

```
update openquery (LINKSERVERID, 'select tng_email from user_list where tng_id = 62873') 
  set tng_email = 'blah@blah.com';
```

... but I get the following error ...

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKSERVERID" returned message "Key column information is insufficient or incorrect.
>   Too many rows were affected by update.".

FYI: `tng_id` is the primary key.

How do I fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to include the key in the select query, so try this:

```
update openquery(
  LINKSERVERID, 'select tng_id, tng_email from user_list where tng_id = 62873'
) set tng_email = 'blah@blah.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above from jpw, but it didn't work for me.

I developed a trigger of which I also received the same error using the code below:

```
begin

    if TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
    return

    declare @JCid       int =   (select top 1   iJCMasterID from inserted)

    begin
        update L set uiJCTxCMLineNumber = NewLineNum
        from (
        select
            rank() over (order by idJCTxLines) NewLineNum
        ,   iJCMasterID
        ,   uiJCTxCMLineNumber
        ,   idJCTxLines
        from    _btblJCTxLines
        where iJCMasterID =  @JCid
        ) L
        where   iJCMasterID =  @JCid
    end
end
go
```

However, I resolved it by changing it to :

```
begin

    if TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
    return

    declare @JCid       int =   (select top 1   iJCMasterID from inserted)

    begin
        update L set uiJCTxCMLineNumber = NewLineNum
        from (
        select
            rank() over (order by idJCTxLines) NewLineNum
        ,   iJCMasterID
        ,   uiJCTxCMLineNumber
        ,   idJCTxLines
        from    _btblJCTxLines
        where iJCMasterID =  @JCid
        ) L
    join inserted i on L.idJCTxLines = i.idJCTxLines
    end
end
go
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by adding a unique index to the underlying table.